# multiple line spaces in html even after formatting the file

Tags: html, code-formatting, vs-code-settings

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR1kK.png)

## Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, dolor!

```
  <h1 class="classhead">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat,
    tempore!
  </h1>
```

How can I configure VS Code to keep my  tag on a single line after saving?

I’ve tried adjusting the html.format.wrapAttributes and html.format.wrapLineLength settings in my settings.json file, but the issue persists.please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: And you are not using line breaks? It looks like it with the indentation.

Comment: try "html.format.wrapLineLength": 0